# How can I parse CSV file while preserving dictionary values within rows

Tags: python, csv

*If anyone has suggestions on how to format this better I am more than willing to do so.

This is for a homework assignment, the end goal is to normalize the data and insert into a schema that is in 2NF (Second Normal Form) then perform queries on the database. I am thinking I could store the data in a bunch of lists and then insert into the schema from there, how to setup the schema in a way to ensure 2NF is separate question but any suggestions would really help.

As far as the main question regarding parsing goes I am not expecting someone to just code it up for me but I am very much stumped on how this can be done in a way that preserves the dictionary like formatting of certain values.

Below is a snippet from the CSV file (each row is a movie):

```
budget , genres, homepage, id, keywords, original_language, original_title, overview,popularity, production_companies, production_countries, release_date, revenue, runtime, spoken_languages, status, tagline, title, vote_average, vote_count

237000000,"[{""id"": 28, ""name"": ""Action""}, {""id"": 12, ""name"": ""Adventure""}, {""id"": 14, ""name"": ""Fantasy""}, {""id"": 878, ""name"": ""Science Fiction""}]",http://www.avatarmovie.com/,19995,"[{""id"": 1463, ""name"": ""culture clash""}, {""id"": 2964, ""name"": ""future""}, {""id"": 3386, ""name"": ""space war""}, {""id"": 3388, ""name"": ""space colony""}, {""id"": 3679, ""name"": ""society""}, {""id"": 3801, ""name"": ""space travel""}, {""id"": 9685, ""name"": ""futuristic""}, {""id"": 9840, ""name"": ""romance""}, {""id"": 9882, ""name"": ""space""}, {""id"": 9951, ""name"": ""alien""}, {""id"": 10148, ""name"": ""tribe""}, {""id"": 10158, ""name"": ""alien planet""}, {""id"": 10987, ""name"": ""cgi""}, {""id"": 11399, ""name"": ""marine""}, {""id"": 13065, ""name"": ""soldier""}, {""id"": 14643, ""name"": ""battle""}, {""id"": 14720, ""name"": ""love affair""}, {""id"": 165431, ""name"": ""anti war""}, {""id"": 193554, ""name"": ""power relations""}, {""id"": 206690, ""name"": ""mind and soul""}, {""id"": 209714, ""name"": ""3d""}]",en,Avatar,"In the 22nd century, a paraplegic Marine is dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission, but becomes torn between following orders and protecting an alien civilization.",150.437577,"[{""name"": ""Ingenious Film Partners"", ""id"": 289}, {""name"": ""Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation"", ""id"": 306}, {""name"": ""Dune Entertainment"", ""id"": 444}, {""name"": ""Lightstorm Entertainment"", ""id"": 574}]","[{""iso_3166_1"": ""US"", ""name"": ""United States of America""}, {""iso_3166_1"": ""GB"", ""name"": ""United Kingdom""}]",2009-12-10,2787965087,162,"[{""iso_639_1"": ""en"", ""name"": ""English""}, {""iso_639_1"": ""es"", ""name"": ""Espa\u00f1ol""}]",Released,Enter the World of Pandora.,Avatar,7.2,11800
300000000,"[{""id"": 12, ""name"": ""Adventure""}, {""id"": 14, ""name"": ""Fantasy""}, {""id"": 28, ""name"": ""Action""}]",http://disney.go.com/disneypictures/pirates/,285,"[{""id"": 270, ""name"": ""ocean""}, {""id"": 726, ""name"": ""drug abuse""}, {""id"": 911, ""name"": ""exotic island""}, {""id"": 1319, ""name"": ""east india trading company""}, {""id"": 2038, ""name"": ""love of one's life""}, {""id"": 2052, ""name"": ""traitor""}, {""id"": 2580, ""name"": ""shipwreck""}, {""id"": 2660, ""name"": ""strong woman""}, {""id"": 3799, ""name"": ""ship""}, {""id"": 5740, ""name"": ""alliance""}, {""id"": 5941, ""name"": ""calypso""}, {""id"": 6155, ""name"": ""afterlife""}, {""id"": 6211, ""name"": ""fighter""}, {""id"": 12988, ""name"": ""pirate""}, {""id"": 157186, ""name"": ""swashbuckler""}, {""id"": 179430, ""name"": ""aftercreditsstinger""}]",en,Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End,"Captain Barbossa, long believed to be dead, has come back to life and is headed to the edge of the Earth with Will Turner and Elizabeth Swann. But nothing is quite as it seems.",139.082615,"[{""name"": ""Walt Disney Pictures"", ""id"": 2}, {""name"": ""Jerry Bruckheimer Films"", ""id"": 130}, {""name"": ""Second Mate Productions"", ""id"": 19936}]","[{""iso_3166_1"": ""US"", ""name"": ""United States of America""}]",2007-05-19,961000000,169,"[{""iso_639_1"": ""en"", ""name"": ""English""}]",Released,"At the end of the world, the adventure begins.",Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End,6.9,4500
245000000,"[{""id"": 28, ""name"": ""Action""}, {""id"": 12, ""name"": ""Adventure""}, {""id"": 80, ""name"": ""Crime""}]",http://www.sonypictures.com/movies/spectre/,206647,"[{""id"": 470, ""name"": ""spy""}, {""id"": 818, ""name"": ""based on novel""}, {""id"": 4289, ""name"": ""secret agent""}, {""id"": 9663, ""name"": ""sequel""}, {""id"": 14555, ""name"": ""mi6""}, {""id"": 156095, ""name"": ""british secret service""}, {""id"": 158431, ""name"": ""united kingdom""}]",en,Spectre,"A cryptic message from Bond’s past sends him on a trail to uncover a sinister organization. While M battles political forces to keep the secret service alive, Bond peels back the layers of deceit to reveal the terrible truth behind SPECTRE.",107.376788,"[{""name"": ""Columbia Pictures"", ""id"": 5}, {""name"": ""Danjaq"", ""id"": 10761}, {""name"": ""B24"", ""id"": 69434}]","[{""iso_3166_1"": ""GB"", ""name"": ""United Kingdom""}, {""iso_3166_1"": ""US"", ""name"": ""United States of America""}]",2015-10-26,880674609,148,"[{""iso_639_1"": ""fr"", ""name"": ""Fran\u00e7ais""}, {""iso_639_1"": ""en"", ""name"": ""English""}, {""iso_639_1"": ""es"", ""name"": ""Espa\u00f1ol""}, {""iso_639_1"": ""it"", ""name"": ""Italiano""}, {""iso_639_1"": ""de"", ""name"": ""Deutsch""}]",Released,A Plan No One Escapes,Spectre,6.3,4466
250000000,"[{""id"": 28, ""name"": ""Action""}, {""id"": 80, ""name"": ""Crime""}, {""id"": 18, ""name"": ""Drama""}, {""id"": 53, ""name"": ""Thriller""}]",http://www.thedarkknightrises.com/,49026,"[{""id"": 849, ""name"": ""dc comics""}, {""id"": 853, ""name"": ""crime fighter""}, {""id"": 949, ""name"": ""terrorist""}, {""id"": 1308, ""name"": ""secret identity""}, {""id"": 1437, ""name"": ""burglar""}, {""id"": 3051, ""name"": ""hostage drama""}, {""id"": 3562, ""name"": ""time bomb""}, {""id"": 6969, ""name"": ""gotham city""}, {""id"": 7002, ""name"": ""vigilante""}, {""id"": 9665, ""name"": ""cover-up""}, {""id"": 9715, ""name"": ""superhero""}, {""id"": 9990, ""name"": ""villainess""}, {""id"": 10044, ""name"": ""tragic hero""}, {""id"": 13015, ""name"": ""terrorism""}, {""id"": 14796, ""name"": ""destruction""}, {""id"": 18933, ""name"": ""catwoman""}, {""id"": 156082, ""name"": ""cat burglar""}, {""id"": 156395, ""name"": ""imax""}, {""id"": 173272, ""name"": ""flood""}, {""id"": 179093, ""name"": ""criminal underworld""}, {""id"": 230775, ""name"": ""batman""}]",en,The Dark Knight Rises,"Following the death of District Attorney Harvey Dent, Batman assumes responsibility for Dent's crimes to protect the late attorney's reputation and is subsequently hunted by the Gotham City Police Department. Eight years later, Batman encounters the mysterious Selina Kyle and the villainous Bane, a new terrorist leader who overwhelms Gotham's finest. The Dark Knight resurfaces to protect a city that has branded him an enemy.",112.31295,"[{""name"": ""Legendary Pictures"", ""id"": 923}, {""name"": ""Warner Bros."", ""id"": 6194}, {""name"": ""DC Entertainment"", ""id"": 9993}, {""name"": ""Syncopy"", ""id"": 9996}]","[{""iso_3166_1"": ""US"", ""name"": ""United States of America""}]",2012-07-16,1084939099,165,"[{""iso_639_1"": ""en"", ""name"": ""English""}]",Released,The Legend Ends,The Dark Knight Rises,7.6,9106
```

There are 19 columns (column attributes are shown in row 1), the 4th column attribute "id" is the unique identifier for each row i.e. movie. Certain columns contain a list of dictionaries, for example the genres column in row 2 contains:

```
[{""id"": 28, ""name"": ""Action""}, {""id"": 12, ""name"": ""Adventure""}, {""id"": 14, ""name"": ""Fantasy""}, {""id"": 878, ""name"": ""Science Fiction""}]
```

Below is what I am currently doing which is just resulting in a list of strings for each attribute column:

```
import csv

budgets = []
genres = []
homepage = []
mainID = []
keywords = []
original_language = []
original_title = []
overview = []
popularity = []
production_companies = []
production_countries = []
release_date = []
revenue = []
runtime = []
spoken_languages = []
status = []
tag_line = []
title = []
vote_avg = []
vote_count = []
key_id = []

with open('tmdb_5000_movies.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    skip_attributes_row = next(csv_reader)
    for item in csv_reader:

        budgets.append(item[0])
        genres.append(item[1])
        homepage.append(item[2])
        mainID.append(item[3])
        keywords.append(item[4])
        original_language.append(item[5])
        original_title.append(item[6])
        overview.append(item[7])
        popularity.append(item[8])
        production_companies.append(item[9])
        production_countries.append(item[10])
        release_date.append(item[11])
        revenue.append(item[12])
        runtime.append(item[13])
        spoken_languages.append(item[14])
        status.append(item[15])
        tag_line.append(item[16])
        title.append(item[17])
        vote_avg.append(item[18])
        vote_count.append(item[19])
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of expected output.

Comment: I can edit the post, essentially I want each column in its own list but columns like "genres" are causing problems and need to be separated into two lists, one storing genre_id and the other storing genre_name.

Comment: *"each column in its own list"*: As I don't see the benefit of doing so you have to flatten the column `genres list` doing `genres.extend(<column generes list>)`. Are you aware that you are dealing with `json` column data?